# Postpone loading stores in Application.js

Tags: javascript, rest, authentication, extjs

How can I postpone loading stores in my Application.js file?

The issue is that I need to first authenticate to get my cookie before I load stores with rest proxies, otherwise I get a bunch of 401 errors.

Removing the required stores from Application.js does not work (the app fails to load). Thus, I need to figure out a way to postpone loading the required stores until after I authenticate successfully.

My login subsystem is based on this: [sample login for ExtJS](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/guides/tutorials/login_app.html)
where my main view gets loaded if the authentication is successful (that is, writes to local storage, as per the relevant section below in Application.js)

My Application.js looks like:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true,
    paths: {
        'Ext.ux.exporter': 'exporter',
        'Overrides': 'overrides'
    }
});

Ext.define('cardioCatalogQT.Application', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',

    name: 'cardioCatalogQT',

    requires: [
        'Ext.app.*',
        'cardioCatalogQT.config.Config',
        'Ext.ux.exporter.Exporter',
        'Ext.state.CookieProvider',
        'Ext.window.MessageBox',
        'Ext.tip.QuickTipManager',
        'Ext.form.Panel',
        'Ext.ux.form.MultiSelect',
        'Ext.ux.form.ItemSelector',
        'cardioCatalogQT.*',
        'Ext.overrides.selection.CheckboxModel',
        'Ext.overrides.view.MultiSelectorSearch'
    ],

    stores: [
        'Attributes',
        'BasicVitals',
        'Diagnoses',
        'Labs',
        'Procedures',
        'Payload',
        'Queries',
        'Results',
        'TestResults',
        'Races',
        'Ethnicities'
    ],

    init: function() {

    },

    views: [
        'cardioCatalogQT.view.login.Login',
        'cardioCatalogQT.view.main.Main'
    ],

    launch: function () {

        Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled: true});

        // Static parameters
        cardioCatalogQT.config = {

            protocol: 'http://',
            host: 'localhost',
            apiGetQ: '/queryview/api/test', 
            apiWriteQ: '/queryview/api/create',
            apiReadQ: '/remote_query_get',
            remove: 'none'
        };


        // It's important to note that this type of application could use
        // any type of storage, i.e., Cookies, LocalStorage, etc.
        var loggedIn;

        // Check to see the current value of the localStorage key
        loggedIn = localStorage.getItem("CCLoggedIn");

        // This ternary operator determines the value of the TutorialLoggedIn key.
        // If TutorialLoggedIn isn't true, we display the login window,
        // otherwise, we display the main view
        Ext.widget(loggedIn ? 'main-view' : 'login');

        // TODO - Launch the application

        Ext.onReady(function () {


        });
    }


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable store [`autoLoad`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.data.Store.html#cfg-autoLoad) config. In that case the store should not load at all when you open the app.

After you are logged in, you will have to call [`load`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/modern/Ext.data.Store.html#method-load) method on each store.

*I did it like this in my app. Where I needed some additional data before loading the stores.*

Comment: I am trying to add something like this `if (loggedIn) {
    var attributes = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('Attributes');
    attributes.load(); 
    console.log('in conditional');
    console.log(attributes);

   };` to my launch method, but it only fires once. Any suggestions on how to add this control logic based on the `loggedIn` state?

Comment: Got it. I added a listener for `afterrender` to my main view. Thanks!